# loading dictionary values without using setTimeout

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, angular-pipe

**How do we ensure that dictionary values are loaded prior to executing `transform()`?**

I'm attempting to use a pipe transform, but when executing the `transform()` method, my data is not loaded yet!

My transform is implemented like so:

```
  public transform(key: string): string {
    if (!key) {
      throw Error('i18n key must be defined');
    }

    let localizations = this.i18nService.localizations;
    if(localizations != null){
      let value = localizations.find(l=>l.Alias == key);
      if(value != null){
        return value.Value;
      }
    }
    else {
      //console.warn(`Missing translation key: ${key}`);
    }
    return key;
  }
```

**example usage:**

```
let t = this.i18nPipe.transform('myKey')
```

however, this does not work and return null.

when I wrap it in a `setTimeout` then things work:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    let t = this.i18nPipe.transform('myKey')
}, 1000
)
```

here's the implementation of the `I18LoaderServce`:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {StaticContentValue} from "../../models/Configuration/StaticContentValue";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class I18LoaderService {
  private _localizations: Array<StaticContentValue>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  loadLocalizations(){
    this.http.get<Array<StaticContentValue>>('api/configuration/staticcontent').subscribe(d =>{
      this._localizations = d;
    });
  }

  get localizations() {
    return this._localizations
  }
}
```

and if we go down to the backend, c# code, entity framework returns the data like so:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<StaticContentValue>> GetStaticContentValues()
    {
        return await this.dbContext.StaticContentValues.ToArrayAsync();
    }
```

**How do we load the dictionary values to be used in an example like below WITHOUT setTimeout?**

```
let t = this.i18nPipe.transform('myKey')
```

Comment: use promises  with async/await ?

Comment: so sorry, total beginner with angular, @Selvin not sure how your suggestion would resolve the issue. right now its an observable, correct? can you show me an example of what you suggest?

Comment: you set `_localizations` when  `http.get` finished ... where `loadLocalizations` is called? and `18LoaderService.localizations` doesnt return observable it returns `Array<StaticContentValue>` which is null until `http.get` finished

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rz6ksm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Idk your architecture but how about calling `loadLocalizations` during the app initialization? Check `APP_INITIALIZER`: https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER